# Python Regex extract sections for MySQL integrity error

Tags: python, regex

I have the following MySQL error message which is very standard with some section changing depending on the situation:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`D2b3f1ee0ce83`.`maintable`, CONSTRAINT `fk5_maintable_lkpaitechid` FOREIGN KEY (`aitechid`) REFERENCES `lkpaitechid` (`aitechid_cod`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION) [SQL: "UPDATE D2b3f1ee0ce83.maintable SET aitechid = 'AI00002' WHERE rowuuid = '7a867b48-f335-4135-936f-6707bc4d3077'"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

I would like to extract each of its variable parts. So with my minimum Regex experience, I did:

```
p = re.compile('Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`+(\w+)+`.`+(\w+)+`, CONSTRAINT `+(\w+)+` FOREIGN KEY (`+(\w+)+`) REFERENCES `+(\w+)+` (`+(\w+)+`) ON +(\w+)+ +(\w+)+)')
m = p.search(str(e))
if m:
    print("Yes!")
```

I tried other combinations like (*?) but did not work. Any idea how I need to structure the Regex string to make it work?

Comment: Escape literal `(` and `)` and remove `+`s after all `(\w+)`. See https://regex101.com/r/OjdHZr/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your regex is written confines you to only this particular error.  If in general you just wanted to capture the quoted values:

```
p1 = re.compile(r'`(\w+)`')
m1 = p1.findall(str(e))

m1

# ['D2b3f1ee0ce83',
#  'maintable',
#  'fk5_maintable_lkpaitechid',
#  'aitechid',
#  'lkpaitechid',
#  'aitechid_cod']
```

For the last one, you'll need to do another search:

```
p2 = re.compile(r'ON (\w+) ([\w ]+)\)')
m2 = p2.search(str(e))

m2.groups()

# ('UPDATE', 'NO ACTION')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>>> t = """Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`D2b3f1ee0ce83`.`maintable`, CONSTRAINT `fk5_maintable_lkpaitechid` FOREIGN KEY (`aitechid`) REFERENCES `lkpaitechid` (`aitechid_cod`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION) [SQL: "UPDATE D2b3f1ee0ce83.maintable SET aitechid = 'AI00002' WHERE rowuuid = '7a867b48-f335-4135-936f-6707bc4d3077'"] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)"""
>>> r = r'''([`] # Start a match group what has an optional backtick
...     \b # use a 'word boundary'
...     [\d\w`_\.]+ # any of these characters at least once
...     \b # use a 'word boundary'
...     [`])''' # optional backtick, closing match group
>>> re.findall(r, t, re.VERBOSE)
['`D2b3f1ee0ce83`.`maintable`', '`fk5_maintable_lkpaitechid`', '`aitechid`', '`lkpaitechid`', '`aitechid_cod`']
```

Adding a "prefix" to filter on more lines should now be nice enough. I did include the backticks as is would be easy enough to remove them with [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Take not of the [`re.VERBOSE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to make this more readable